# wscript not found - Command line windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows, wsh

I was trying to use a javascript script to tidy up my itunes library.

My system is windows 8. I am running my javascript file with node.

```
c:\Users\SaythandBec\Desktop>node RemoveDeadTracks.js

c:\Users\SaythandBec\Desktop\RemoveDeadTracks.js:46
var     iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
                    ^
ReferenceError: WScript is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\SaythandBec\Desktop\RemoveDeadTracks.js:46:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

c:\Users\SaythandBec\Desktop>
```

Is there anyway to get wscript to run so I can execute the script?

Comment: Any particular reason you're running the script through `node` instead of `wscript`?